# Wordpress as Wishlist Application

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

What I'm trying to do is allow registered users to create a list of gift items they would like for Christmas. So I've created a custom post type called 'gift' and a custom taxonomy of 'list' but I can't figure out how to relate the 'list' to the user. I would like to allow users to create multiple lists, but I can see a problem where 2 users may create the same list name and therefore causing headaches on which list belongs to who.

Have I set this up the right way? What would you do differently?

Answer (score 2):

You have the user id# that uniquely identifies the user.  So prepend the user id value to the list name the user chooses, to save the list value.  For example, if user #1234 creates a list called xmas, then do

```
$args = wp_insert_term ('1234_xmas', 'list');
```

Next add a custom field to the user.  And store 'xmas' into that field.
See: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields